# inserting table values from one table to another

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have two tables in SQL. I need to insert the data from one table to another.I have done it successfully, but the problem is I need to extra add one column value from text box. I will show my code

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str1 = "insert into table2(Code,Qty,UPrice,Total) select Code,Qty,UPrice,Total from table1 ;";    
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", TextBox1.Text);
    da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    da1.Fill(ds1, "Code");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
    con.Close();
}
```

Here I need to add Num to my table2 that is not in the table1. So I need to add it from textbox1. How can I add that Num value to the all data from textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String str1 = "insert into table2(Code,Qty,UPrice,Total,Num) select Code,Qty,UPrice,Total,'"+TextBox1.Text+"' from table1 ;";    
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
da1.Fill(ds1);
GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik for ur help

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Num` is your column name, you can modify your query as

```
insert into table2(Code,Qty,UPrice,Total, Num) 
select Code,Qty,UPrice,Total, textbox1.Text from table1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set your dynamic value in a temporary variable.

```
String temp = TextBox1.Text;

Now use this variable with your insert query

String str1 = "insert into table2(Code,Qty,UPrice,Total,Num) 
select Code,Qty,UPrice,Total,'"+temp+"' from table1 ;";
```